# Local expo-notifications trigger Daily(SDK 39.0.0)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the local notification and I am using the new notification module.

In the previous version, it had a repeat argument for `Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync` to work yearly or monthly.

In the new module, the repeated option was removed.

How can I be able to repeat my notification monthly or yearly?

This is the documentation in Expo: [Scheduling Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#scheduling-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentations, counting the yearly/monthly by seconds.

```js
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
    
    Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: 'Remember to drink water!'
      },
      trigger: {
        seconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
        repeats: true
      },
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also found ```Notifications.CalendarTriggerInput``` in documentation which can be more specific(monthly/yearly) for IOS.